# what is the difference between passing method name directly or by user input to respond_to method in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I wrote the following code:

```
obj = Object.new

def obj.talk
    puts "Talk called"
end

if obj.respond_to?(talk)
    obj.send(talk)
else
    puts "No talk"
end
```

which outputs following:

```
undefined local variable or method `talk' for main:Object (NameError)
```

But when I pass it through user input it works as:

```
obj = Object.new

def obj.talk
    puts "Talk called"
end

request = gets.chomp

if obj.respond_to?(request)
    obj.send(request)
else
    puts "No talk"
end
```

which outputs `Talk called` when entering the string `talk` from terminal.

Comment: Have you tried obj.send(:talk)

Comment: Yeah that gives the same o/p @tkhurana96

Comment: `obj.respond_to?(talk)` understands `talk` as a variable, but no such variable exists (just like `obj.respond_to?(request)` understands `request` as the variable where you have your input). You want to send the symbol name of the method: `obj.respond_to?(:talk)`, or the string name `obj.respond_to?("talk")`

Comment: And have you tried obj.respond_to(:talk)

Comment: ...and there's no need for `obj.respond_to?(:talk)` since you've just defined the method `talk` (on `obj`'s singleton class)! Of course `obj` responds to `:talk`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Amadan, it works by using the symbol name of the method. Following works.

```
obj = Object.new;

def obj.talk
    puts "Talk called"
end

if obj.respond_to?(:talk)
    obj.send(:talk)
else
    puts "No talk"
end
```

> Talk called

Comment: As I noted in a comment on the question, how could `obj.respond_to?(:talk)` return anything other than `true` considering that you've just defined the method `talk` on `obj`? It's like saying, "The light is red! If the light is red, stop!", rather than, "The light is red! Stop!".